# ZPL PDF-417 barcode symbol generates with extra spaces on Intermec PM4i

Tags: zpl, pdf417

We are designing a label to be printed from SAP to an Intermec PM4i printer in ZSim mode. The printer is using the Generic Text driver, meaning that we can send raw ZSim-compatible ZPL code to the printer.

The content of the PDF417 barcode must be one string exactly 100 characters in length. This is my customer's requirement, not mine.

We developed an application that generates the proper ZPL code with all the characters in their proper position. However, when validating the printed barcode with a scanner using Motorola's 123Scan2 utility, all our data is there but we keep getting 6 additional spaces at around position 70 of the string, resulting in a string 106 characters long.

We also sent the ZPL code to the printer from a text editor and observed the same results. Below code snippet is what we are using to generate the barcode.

```
^XA
^MMT
^PW609
^LL0203
^BY2,4^FT331,111^B7N,4,0,,,N
^FH\^FDMN23012635105         A                           MN239598U205        QDR-032565.14812          H030^FS
^XZ
```

I have also experimented with sending the spaces as hex and that actually resulted in more extra spaces.

I am not sure what we are missing. Any ideas or suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: After a little more reading, it appears I am getting closer. Apparently, the ratio of columns and rows in the PDF417 symbol determines/affects the number of "code words". The documentation says that it defaults to 6 by 12 (a 1:2 ratio), which gives 72 code words. When checking my generated labels, sure enough, the data breaks at 72 characters, six blank spaces are added and then the rest of the data. I tried messing with the columns and rows settings, but I still get the same problem. I am still stumped.

Comment: After some research, I learned a pretty neat story which reminded me of "The Story of Mel".

The developer for the legacy system knew that there would be 6 blank spaces inserted at position 73, so he cleverly designed the legacy label 6 characters short and positioned a 28 character field so it would run from positions 51 to 72 (instead of 78), intentionally truncating the last 6 characters to allow the interpreter to fill the rest of the field with blanks. The end result being the required 100 character PDF417 barcode symbol with every field precisely in the correct position.

Here's to Mel.